# Any way to debug JS issue in IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, banner

I have a JS script which works in every browser except IE 9. I am not thrown any errors in my IDE or on the page itself but the loading icon just seems to continuously rotate instead of loading the image.

Page can be seen at:
http://www.nacdbenefits.com/jmarston4

I have used tools like Firebug in Firefox before to recognize some issues but this one is stumping me. Anybody had a similar issue before?

Comment: Press F12 in IE for debugging after you install http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: @have this installed - don't seem to be able to find any JS issues. It has to be a IE conflict somewhere because it opens in every other browser.

Comment: By some reason your `$('#lofslidecontent45').lofJSidernews` does not run. If you run it later in developer console of IE - it starts. I see this code in page source, but I do not see it in the parsed DOM structure of the page. I think `gajaxscroller.min.js` somehow affects it, try to put `gajaxscroller.min.js` below the slider part in the header.

Comment: @Cheery - thanks for the suggestion. I even tried removing it completely with no luck. Very strange.

Comment: The problem is exactly there. The js file is loading, I've checked it. But IE unable to parse to bottom part of your header or something affects it, skipping the part with slider code. Look by yourself http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/7117/86532984.jpg

Comment: Or try to rewrite the style element after it. It is in one line, may be IE does not like it by some reason

Comment: I ran the same DOM inspection with and without the lines you mention (they are a part of a php include.) I removed and still nothing displaying. Wiped out all code and still nothing but the DOM does match the page source

Comment: `the DOM does match the page source` The header is still missing script code related to the slider. The weird thing that it is also missing in Chrome, for example, but somehow it is able to run the script http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7196/56641908.jpg  ***BTW, your URLs are missing HTTP in them.***

Comment: @cheery - the urls do not need http. The pages switch between http and https. Using // reference allows the page to switch between the two. As I mentioned, I have removed the php include for the google ajax scroller as mentioned and it does not affect the file. Something else seems to be happening.

Comment: Try to add alert like that `$(document).ready(function(){alert(1);$('#lofslidecontent45').` for testing purposes.  Check if it is called in IE.

Comment: yep - it was: http://screencast.com/t/dQ1AAnUxbyi

Comment: Then, by some reason, the DOM structure is not `ready` for the slider. I tried it in developer console, as I wrote above, it starts manually without any problem. Again, for testing purposes, add setTimeout to run the code in `$(document).ready` after some period of time. ps: and you have errors on the page http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)